# 3d cloud viewer?

Tags: graphics, 3d, point-clouds

I have a file which contains a bunch of points with their x,y, z locations.I am looking for a simple viewer where in I can load this point data and view it .Rotation is essential for me to check the depth of the cloud being generated .Can someone point out a light weight viewer with minimum installation overhead for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used [MeshLab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeshLab) and it worked well for me. IIRC it uses your average Windows installer.

You could also try [CyArk](http://archive.cyark.org/viewer-help) viewer (a Java applet), or [Leica Cyclone](http://hds.leica-geosystems.com/en/Leica-Cyclone_6515.htm) -- I haven't used either one.

Of course if your data format is not a standard one, they may not be able to read it.

Comment: I do not have any format right now its just a set of core 3D raw points

Comment: also I just need to see the 3d points ...mesh lab on the other hand expects information about the faces and normals?

Comment: MeshLab can load mere point sets, without faces and normals. E.g. it comes with a sample called chameleon4k.pts, which it can load and display. (And rotate.) The format is EXPE point set.

Comment: I just came across this question, and used MeshLab to display my point data. Here's a reference for the .pts format, which is a plain text space-delimited file

http://www.las-vegas.uni-osnabrueck.de/index.php/tutorials2/8-understanding-file-formats-pts-and-3d-files

Answer (score 3):

R+ is an open source statistical program that I have used for this exact purpose.  It can be accomplished in only a few lines of code.

First add the rgl and plotrix libraries.
Enter the following code:

```
pcd <- read.table(file.choose(),sep="",skip=10)
names(pcd) <- c("x","y","z")
plot3d(pcd$x,pcd$y,pcd$z,col=color.scale(pcd$z,c(0,1,1),c(1,1,0),c(1,0,1)))
```

Where pcd is the type of file (if I remember correctly), the first ten lines are skipped as they are a header (`skip=10`) and `sep""` represents the delimiter used in the file.  This last line of code plots the points and sets the color based upon depth.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for [Paraview](https://www.paraview.org/). I am shocked that no one mentioned it before I did.
 No matter which OS you use, Windows, Mac OS or Linux you can use it without any (big) problems. (You know software always has bugs)

[Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/) is good too. In fact you can convert file format easily to make sure they can be used in different software, if you can learn Python.

I do believe someones has already done it. Eg. .off (Meshlab format) to .vtk(Paraview format), like this [one](https://github.com/alexxsun/Converters/tree/master/meshes).

Update1:
Most visualization softwares are user-friendly, so maybe the problem you have is mainly about how to convert the source data you have to the specified format which can be used in these viewers. It may be helpful if there is an example of data you have.

Answer (score 0):

matlab is a quite good tool to visualize your pcl, expecially for further analysis.